# Can I make these elements align left horizontally

Tags: html, css

All , I have html like below . I want `H2` element and `Div` align left horizontally. please help me . thanks.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>xxx</h2><div>xxxx</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can align element by float in your code make the h2 and div `float:left;`

**Note:**

1. Absolutely positioned elements ignores the float property!
2. Floating elements can overlap with the margin, border and padding areas of other elements   when the floating element is wider or higher than the element it is inside
3. Element before floating element will not affected only after floating element will affected

Answer (score 2):

You can using css rule like this:

```
h2{float: left;}
```

Comment: This won't cause his second div (<div>xxxx</div>) to fall below the h2 element unless the div is floated left as well.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/Mdx27/. if second div (<div>xxxx</div>) still fall below, maybe you need to normalized your css code.

Comment: You can download dormalized CSS source here: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You should set width for both h2 and div and make sure its well within the page width. And then you should use `float: left` in css style.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the float: left property on the div element. Here is a jsfiddle with example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXMcn/)

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>xxx</h2><div id="test">xxxx</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Then in your CSS you would have:

```
#test {

    float: left;
}​
```

Alternatively, you could set your h2 to display as a block element.

```
h2 {
    display: block;
}
```

This would cause your div element to fall below the h2 element, since rendering it as block will take up all horizontal space.

Comment: i have edited your link why you pasted the link again when there is already link

Comment: Yea, I noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in between `<head>` and `</head>`

```
 <style>
      body{
           text-align:left;
      }
 </style>
```

Floating would also work.  Odd that on your browser it's not already displaying to the left.